# How to remove the first screen from route in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, materialpageroute

I am creating a loading screen for an app. This loading screen is the first screen to be shown to the user. After 3 seconds the page will navigate to the HomePage. everything is working fine. But when the user taps back button the loading screen will be shown again.

**FIRST PAGE CODE**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(
        Duration(
          seconds: 3,
        ), () {
      // Navigator.of(context).pop(); // THIS IS NOT WORKING
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(
          size: 400,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HOMEPAGE CODE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('HomePage'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add `Navigator.of(context).pop();` before calling the HomePage but that is not working. This will show a blank black screen.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use [`pushReplacement`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html) instead of the [`push`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) method.

To solve your problem just replace this code:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomePage(),
  ),
);
```

with this:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => HomePage(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I found the same problem as you. The problem with replace is that it only works once, but I don't know why it doesn't work as it should. For this after a few attempts, I read the official guide and this method exists: pushAndRemoveUntil (). In fact, push on another widget and at the same time remove all the widgets behind, including the current one. You must only create a one Class to management your root atrough the string. This is the example:

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static const main_home= "/main";


  static Route<dynamic> generatorRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  final args = settings.arguments;

  switch (settings.name) {

  case main_home:
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainHome());
    break;

  }
 }
}
```

This class must be add to the Main in:

> MaterialApp( onGenerateRoute: ->RouteGenerator.generatorRoute)

Now to use this method, just write:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              RouteGenerator.main_home,
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false
            );
```